# Handling font formatting in iOS

Tags: ios

Under Android, I am used to the `Html.fromHtml` method so that I can use pseudo html in my translations like `<string name="xxx">&lt;b>%s&lt;/b> @%s</string>` to format username with her company and having username in bold.

How do I do the same kind of thing under iOS ?

Am I required to concat multiple `NSAttributedString` manually in code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really that familiar with Android but you can do the following on iOS.

Lets say you have a string like so:

```html
NSString *myString = @"<html>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <head>
                    <style type="text/css">
                        body { font: 12pt 'Avenir'; color: #300c78; }
                        i { color: #4223ae; }
                    </style>
                </head>
                <body>Check-in: <i>2018-07-29 13:16:28</i><br>Duration: <i>4 Minute, 1 Second</i><br>Venue (Near) <i>-----</i></body>
            </html>";
```

Then you can do this with a UILabel

```
myLabel.attributedText =
    [[NSAttributedString alloc]
     initWithData: [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
     options: @{ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType }
     documentAttributes: nil
     error: &err];
```

You will get a nicely formatted attributed string that will display correctly.